# Tomcat don't find two properties file

Tags: server, tomcat7

I have a issue, when I start a tomcat 7 server and start my webapp I can see in the logs that cannot find 2 properties file, but I don`t know what is the path where tomcat is searching it. How I can see what is the path??

Thanks and regards

Comment: Which property file it is not finding?

Comment: Two CatalogManager, I think that is for classpath, but I don't know. I don`t know how to configure the path for Tomcat find this properties. 

Thanks